# BAM Dashboard Graphical Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I was successfully able to make a connection between WSO2 AS and WSO2 BAM. For the first time running,my WSO2 AS server was shown in the select BAM "server section" with the port address. The graph was shown when I click any one of "ALL,Month and Day. But when I click "now" it show blank page.saying "No data available. Please visit our docs to see how to configure AS monitoring". Next day when I run the same program once more, This time "ALL" and "Month" have the response graph. Except both the "Day" and "NOW" shows blank page with same error. My doubt is why the "now" graph is not displaying the result.Even after restart the server once more, still it showing only two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not bugs they are the functionality of the toolbox. "NOW" shows the data received within the current hour (as I remember ). "Day" shows the data received during the current day. After 1 hour you run the sample, data will not be shown under "NOW". On the next day after the sample was run, "Day" data will not be shown. I think you understand the rationale now.